# Fix the Error which appears on button click in Android Studio / Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, error-handling

In my Android Application every time when i click the Button the Error appears.

Kotlin:

```
fun goClicked(view: View) {
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditText?.text.toString(), passwordEditText?.text.toString())
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                logIn()
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Toast.makeText(this, "Account nicht gefunden!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
}
```

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="83dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="84dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="215dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
    android:onClick="goClicked"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="#F8000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText" />
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: spiels.dev.easysender, PID: 31395
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method goClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button3'
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14177)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27807)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7037)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Every time when i click on the button this error message is shown.

I hope you can help me
Best Regards Sandro

Comment: Clearly mentioned the reason on the stack trace: **Could not find method goClicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute**. Check your `Activity/Fragment` code where you use the layout.

Comment: Your button method in your activity should be public. You might have made it private right now check.

Comment: Post the `Activity/Fragment` declaration (the one with class...)?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are calling the same function in another button

> id:'button3'

so when you click on the goClicked function Android search for all the ref. that need it.

> TL;DR. Change the name of your function goClicked and the issue should be solved.